# How to activate the Scripts menu in iTerm2 on Mac?

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, iterm

I have created a custom AppleScript that works, and placed it in the folder:
~/Library/Application Support/iTerm/Scripts

As described in the documentation here:
http://www.iterm2.com/#/section/documentation/scripting

However I don't see a "Scripts" menu in iTerm2 after restarting, as advertised.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy. For some reason, iTerm only shows scripts that were saved with the "Run Only" option (I think they're precompiled scripts in a binary format) in that Script menu. Unfortunately, these scripts cannot be modified, so it's a good idea to also save them as text files or as editable applescript documents.